# a problem understanding open covers and compact sets,does an countably infinite series of open interval with width tend to $0$ cover a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently trying to self study rudin's book  and I have a problem understanding covers and subcovers and compactness

> **Definition** By an open cover of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$ we mean a collection ${G_a}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $E \subset \bigcup_a G_a$.
>
> **Definition** A subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be compact if every
> open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover.
> More explicitly, the requirement is that if ${ G_a}$ is an open cover of $K$, then
> there are finitely many indices $a_1 ,... ,a_n$ such that
> $K \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n G_{a_k}$.

now I have a problem with the possibility that any infinite cover of a compact set have finite sub cover and my problem rise from the question does an countably infinite series of open interval with width tend to $0 $ cover a closed interval,

what I mean is imagine the interval $[0,1]$ now I will divide it by $x_0 =0$ $x_1 =0.5 $ and $x_k =2^{-(k+1)} + x_{k-1}$ then $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty [x_{k-1}, x_k]$ clearly $lim_{n} x_n =1 $  denote the mid point of the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ by $m_{k}$
now I will define series of infinite intervals,   let $m_0$ = some negative number like $-1$ and make the interval $I_k =(m_k, x_k)$ clearly $[x_{k-1}, x_k) \subset I_k $ the question is does $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ cover $1$? the question might be pretty obvious and the answer is no as for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $1$ is not an element of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$ but what make me ask the question is the $\infty$  I know how to deal with limits of infinity  but this is not a limit it is countably infinite many interval and I cannot get my head around the concept of infinity yet It seem very weird and new to me. If the answer is: yes, it cover the whole interval then no finite subcover and cover the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Your problem seems to be you don't properly understand the definition of an arbitrary union of sets. This is definition 2.9 in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" (third edition) if this the book you are following.

Comment: @FZan  I still don'y understand why 1 is not in the set I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe I'm being tired and stupid but I figure, according to the rule $x_k:=x_{k-1}/2+x_{k-1}=(3/2)x_{k-1}$, we have $x_2=0.75$ and $x_3=0.375+0.75=1.125>1$ so clearly the limit of the $x_n$ is *not* $1$ (in fact this sequence should diverge) and clearly also there is a finite subcover.

Comment: So I guess you made a typo in the definition of the sequence. Leaving that aside, "the concept of infinity" is not really a thing or an issue here. The definition of the union can be expressed entirely in finite terms. $1$ is in the union if and only if it is contained in one of the intervals $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. **The union of subsets of $\Bbb R$ is not the "limit" of these subsets**. For instance, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[0,1-1/n]=[0,1)$ and does *not* contain the "limit point" $1$.

Comment: @FShrike no you are not too tired  or  stupid if someone is stupid here this will be me the sequence $x_k$ should donate the geometric series $\sum_{k>0} 2^{-k}$ and in general the some is defended as a recursive sequence $s_{n+1}=s_n + y_n$ and somehow I made a mistake in the $y_n$ and didn't notice

Comment: By definition, something belongs to the union of a bunch of sets if and only if it belongs to at least one of those sets. If you want to know whether $1$ belongs to the union of your sets $I_k$, you just have to figure out whether there is some $k$ such that $1\in I_k$. Ask yourself: is $x_k\gt1$ for some $k$?